# How Do I Move The Label After Last Bar with Pine Script ? I use ta.barssince() but still get problem

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I draw a line and a label to mark at the position where the candlestick meets the conditions. Every time a new candlestick that meets this condition appears, the indicator deletes the old line and label to draw a new line and label.
However,I would like to move the label to the future position 3 candlesticks away from the last candlestick but still belong to this line to avoid overlapping on the nearby candlesticks.
Please take the time to help me! Thank you so much.

The label is overlapping nearby bars:

[image: the label is overlapping nearby bars]

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

var lastbar = 0
var linesl = line.new(na,na,na,na)
var label labelsl = na
barsincecond = 0
cross = ta.crossover(close,ta.hma(close,30))
distance = ta.barssince(cross)
if cross
    lastbar := bar_index
    barsincecond := distance

    line.delete(linesl)
    linesl := line.new(x1=lastbar, y1=close , x2=lastbar + barsincecond +5, y2=close, extend=extend.right, color = color.rgb(230, 75, 18), style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    
    label.delete(labelsl)
    labelsl := label.new(bar_index + barsincecond + 5, close, text='Close ' + str.tostring(math.round((close - close*3*0.01)/syminfo.mintick)*syminfo.mintick), color=color.rgb(230, 75, 18), style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color.white)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `last_bar_index` as the x variable to plot the label at the last bar. If you still want it three bars beyond that, just use `last_bar_index+3`

The code with the change:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

var lastbar = 0
var linesl = line.new(na,na,na,na)
var label labelsl = na
barsincecond = 0
cross = ta.crossover(close,ta.hma(close,30))
distance = ta.barssince(cross)
if cross
    lastbar := bar_index
    barsincecond := distance

    line.delete(linesl)
    linesl := line.new(x1=lastbar, y1=close , x2=lastbar + barsincecond +5, y2=close, extend=extend.right, color = color.rgb(230, 75, 18), style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    
    label.delete(labelsl)
    labelsl := label.new(last_bar_index, close, text='Close ' + str.tostring(math.round((close - close*3*0.01)/syminfo.mintick)*syminfo.mintick), color=color.rgb(230, 75, 18), style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color.white)
```

---

Edit 1:

Changed the code to make it more consistent and update on every new bar:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

var linesl = line.new(na,na,na,na)
var label labelsl = na
barsincecond = 0
cross = ta.crossover(close,ta.hma(close,100))

lastbar = ta.valuewhen(cross, bar_index, 0)
lastclose = ta.valuewhen(cross, close, 0)

if barstate.islast

    line.delete(linesl)
    linesl := line.new(x1=lastbar, y1=lastclose, x2=last_bar_index, y2=lastclose, extend=extend.none, color = color.rgb(230, 75, 18), style=line.style_solid, width=2)

    label.delete(labelsl)
    labelsl := label.new(last_bar_index, lastclose, text='Close ' + str.tostring(math.round((lastclose - lastclose*3*0.01)/syminfo.mintick)*syminfo.mintick), color=color.rgb(230, 75, 18), style=label.style_label_left, textcolor=color.white)
```

Comment: Thank for your kind! Really cool for this built-in variable. I got it now !

Comment: Thank you. Please mark this answer as the solution if it helped solve your question.

Comment: Excuse me, but when I check it in TF 1m, the labels don't update to new position at every new bar ??

Comment: I have updated the code. The previous code was not updated at every new bar since the code to update the line and label was only updated with each new cross. The updated code will get around that and plot the line until the new bar and will update as usual for a new cross.

Comment: It really worked very well. Many thanks for your enthusiasm! And how can I mark this answer as the solution? Is it clicking on the blue tick above? I am newbie.

Comment: It is already accepted as a solution, but you can upvote the answer if it helped you.